# Distribution of sum of squares of elements of multinomial random vector

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, multinomial-distribution, convolution

I am interested in the distribution of the sum of squared elements of a multinomial distribution. Specifically if:
$$\vec X \sim \text{multinomial}(N,\vec p)$$

What is the distribution of: $$\sum_{i=1}^{k} X_i^2 $$ where k = dim(X).

Put another way, if:
$$\hat{\text{var}} X = \frac {\sum X_i^2}{k} - \frac{\left(\sum X_i\right)^2}{k^2} $$
$$= \frac {\sum X_i^2}{k} -\frac {N^2} {k^2}$$
What is the distribution of $\hat{\text{var} X}$?

I know that this has been derived for the dirichlet distribution:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/0704.1415.pdf

And that we can calculate the expectation of this quantity, but what about the probability mass function? Is there a closed form expression, or approximation for this distribution (eg assuming $p$, and/or $X_i$s are independent binomial?

Comment: I think that whoever downvoted this should probably explain their downvote.

Comment: Your title doesn't match your body text as far as I can see. The means and variances and covariances of the elements are all easy, but if you're dealing with the sum of the squares of the first $k$ elements, then that's not "the variance of the multinomial". Do you need the distribution of the sum of the squares for something? (If so, I think your title should change to reflect that)

Comment: Glen, thank you for your comment. I have edited the body to better reflect the question and the title. Is it any clearer now?

Comment: You should also edit the title, maybe "sum of squares of elements of multinomial random vector"